# how to represent decision tree with yes /no?

Tags: xml, database, decision-tree

I want to save data in this diagram as an xml file or database file.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would represent the tree as a directed graph where the decisions are the nodes and the answers are the edges that lead to other decisions. As xml this could be a linear list of decision elements with id attributes 1..n and yes/no ids that connect to other decisions:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<decision_tree>
<decisions>
    <decision id="1" y="2" n="3">
        Power comes on?
    </decision>
    <decision id="2" y="4" n="5">
        Live screen?
    </decision>
    <decision id="3" y="6" n="7">
        Good AC power source?
    </decision>
    <!-- ... -->
</decisions>
<actions>
    <action id="5">
        Procede to Video Failure chart
    </action>
    <action id="7">
        Use live outlet.
    </action>
    <!-- ... -->
</actions>
</decision_tree>
```

Comment: Nice and lightweight xml. though I mis the final states!

Comment: Good point @MQoder. I would represent final states like decision nodes but without the yes/no edges. I've added an actions node to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save it as XML, a possibility is to use a structure similar to the following:

```
<question> Power comes on
  <question if="yes">Live screen?
    <answer if="no">Proceed to video failure chart</answer>
    <question if="yes">New Build?
      <answer if="yes">Check power requirement vs rating</answer>
      <answer if="no"> .....
...
...
</question>
```

If you want to save this in a database, the best format depends on your needs and on what kind of database you are using (SQL, noSQL, etc.). Many databases would allow you to store the XML as text object.

Comment: This works for hierarchical decision trees where a decision or action is only reachable via a single path through the tree. It does not support two separate paths leading to the same conclusion or joining paths via a shared decision.

Answer (score 0):

The [Wizard4j](http://wizard4j.org/) uses an XML fomat to describe it's workflows. I'd suggest looking there first and see if there is anything useful

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a 'standard' (widely used) format to store decission tree you can use [PMML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_Model_Markup_Language). For example, [Knime](http://www.knime.org/) uses this format to export decissions tree. In adventage, you can also inform about possibilities of yes or no.

You can found a sample of PMML on [lightpmmlpredictor project](https://github.com/ctrl-alt-d/lightpmmlpredictor).

Using standard format you can use knime to digging your data:

[image]